# How to add Panda 'to_json' output to a rest call

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, rest

I have the following JSON data:

```
x = df.to_json(orient='records')
print(x)

[{"val":"3760","id":"204","quantity":2},{"val":"8221","id":"220","quantity":8}]
```

I want to add the data to my REST call, but it results in the following string in the payload (note: the single quotes around the square bracket:

```
'updateVals': '[{"val":"3760","id":"204","quantity":2},{"val":"8221","id":"220","quantity":8}]'}}
```

The fact that the JASON values are listed as one big string, the REST call results in an HTTP 400 error.

The code is:

```
url = 'my_url'
payload = {
    'client_id': 'my_id',
    'api_key': 'my_key',
    "data": {
        "uuid": "myUUID",
        "timeStamp": "2018-09-12T06:17:48+00:00",
        "updateVals": x
    }
}
```

How do I plug the JSON into the REST call? I assume I have to split the string, or maybe there is a more straightforward answer?

Comment: I don't understand your problem..

Comment: _How do I plug the JSON into the REST call?_ what do you call a REST call? are you posting or getting, or responding to a query? how do you interact with a REST service? `curl`? what is the interface of the API you use? _maybe there is a more straightforward answer?_ there can be a more precise questiion, really.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what you need, JSON is really one big string:

```
x = [{"val":"3760","id":"204","quantity":2},
     {"val":"8221","id":"220","quantity":8}]

>>> json.dumps(x)
>>> '[{"val": "3760", "id": "204", "quantity": 2}, {"val": "8221", "id": "220", "quantity": 8}]'
```